# Pretendo buscar um arquivo com o valor de uma variável

Tags: javascript, react

Gostaria de buscar uma imagem com o valor da variável `valor`, gerada pela função `getRandomInt()`, que gera um número aleatório entre o `max` e o `min`. Meu objetivo é que a cada vez que o usuário acessar o site, uma nova imagem apareça ao lado, inclusive, se alguém souber outra forma de resolver esse problema, eu agradeceria. Por fim, até o momento, eu criei um `switch` para que, a cada valor gerado, busque-se uma imagem determinada, todavia está forma é meio gambiarra.

Só para constar, a função funciona perfeitamente, o problema esta na linha do `import`.

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(1);
    window.crypto.getRandomValues(byteArray);

    var range = max - min + 1;
    var max_range = 256;
    if (byteArray[0] >= Math.floor(max_range / range) * range)
        return getRandomInt(min, max);
    return min + (byteArray[0] % range);
}

const valor = getRandomInt(1,6);

import homeImage from `../../assets/home-images/${valor}.png`;
```

Comment: Se o range é de 1 a 1000 pra que usar getRandomValues e outras coisas? Não é mais fácil criar imagens com o nome de 1.png até 1000.png?

Comment: estou em uma situação semelhante à sua.Também estou interessado em respostas sobre esse tópico, que também aconteceu comigo com o [Topflix.film](https://www.lingvolive.com/pt-br/community/posts/1379719#comments), mas consegui resolver o problema. Lá pude ver que esses fóruns funcionam e oferecem excelentes alternativas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Você pode usar o seguinte código:

```
const image = import(`../../assets/home-images/${valor}.png`);
```

e dentro de um loop, passar ele na tag `<img src={image} />`